# How do I fix this weird shading on my eevee render?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, shaders, lighting

[image: Weird Shading Artifact]

Hey guys while making a phone model, reference to this tutorial :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZPedlX6CMw&t=2182s

Why is this showing me such weird shading, is it because of the two seperate objects or edges or something else, I am a beginner to blender and my first time working with eevee so any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the shadowmap resolution.
[image: cube]

Try changing the shadow bias on the area light.
[image: bias]

You could do either one of these or both at the same time, depending on the desired result.

Comment: Wow, Thanks.
 
It did fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @AtharvaDeodhar Enabling _Contact Shadows_ on the area light "Area" also fixes it.